# How to start tomcat 7 server in eclipse Kepler using java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to start a tomcat server running inside eclipse without going to 'Servers' and clicking 'Run'? I wish to have a functional test that sets a properties file and then start a service.
In the real Functional Testing Environment I am restarting the windows service, but when I want this ability also for when I am developing new tests and the "service" is running locally inside my eclipse.

Any tips/ideas?

Comment: Do you want to start/stop/manage tomcat programmatically using java ?

Comment: You can do this kind of thing with [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org)

Answer (score 1):

to the best of my knowledge you have 3 options (listed in order of preference):

1. [the tomcat maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/run-mojo-features.html). im guessing youre running your tests using some build system (hopefully maven). in which case this has already been taken care of for you.
2. good old System.exec() (or better yet, [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html))- just execute the startup script for tomcat. this is probably the least work and most compatible option (compatible with the results of a normal execution later)
3. class [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html) can be used to launch a minimal, embedded instance of tomcat explicitly for unit testing. you might run into all sorts of small annoying incompatibilities with the "real" runtime env. though (classpath issues, all sorts of small differences etc)

Comment: I am locally running a specific testNG test (or group) using the eclipse testNG plugin, so I think the maven plugin won't help. Using the System.exec() or ProcessBuilder will work, but it won't allow me the benefit of auto publishing and the setup of server I allready defined. So - I still wish I could make the server as it is defined in the 'Servers' tab to run using code...

Comment: @UriCS - still wont reuse the definitions from eclipse, but there's a junit "extension" that handles container startup/shutdown and deployment - arquillian - http://arquillian.org/features/ . has support for tomcat 7 embedded - http://arquillian.org/modules/arquillian-tomcat-embedded-7-container-adapter/. anything beyond that and you'd need to write an eclipse-aware extension for arquillian

Answer (score 0):

You can build a light-weight embedded instance for testing, something along the lines of:

```
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

String TEMP_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

// Init tomcat
tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(0);
tomcat.setBaseDir(TEMP_DIR);
tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(TEMP_DIR);

// Init servlet
File docBase = new File(TEMP_DIR);
Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", docBase.getAbsolutePath());
Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "test", new DefaultServlet());
ctx.addServletMapping("/*", "test");

// Start tomcat
tomcat.init();
tomcat.start();

//--------------------
// Do something useful
//--------------------
tomcat.getEngine().getLogger().info("Logging with embedded tomcat");

// Stop tomcat
if (tomcat.getServer() != null
        && tomcat.getServer().getState() != LifecycleState.DESTROYED) {
    if (tomcat.getServer().getState() != LifecycleState.STOPPED) {
        tomcat.stop();
    }
    tomcat.destroy();
}
```

This syntax works with tomcat 7+ but as far as I know earlier versions use a somewhat different embedding mechanism